# Stack Overflow app not loading content

Tags: support, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

The app on iOS simply shows “Request failed. Tap to retry”. I have never seen this before and it’s been happening for a couple of hours. I’ve tried closing the app, but that didn’t resolve it.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324691/stack-exchange-app-not-working

Comment: The general answer is that the app isn't being maintained at all, but there might be some special configuration that someone knows to fix the issue locally. I'd recommend just using the mobile site though instead of the app.

Comment: So the answer is made that there was a bad deploy causing access_tokens to be invalidated, you have to login/logout to make the app work again (I am not answering here because it has been answered on the cross-site duplicate link)

Comment: I would strongly advice you to use the mobile site of SE/SO family of sites. The mobile app is dumpster fire in comparison. Its not updated from a long time, too.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected too - the Android app over on MSE explicitly states it isn't in active dev, I'd assume the same applies for the other apps and on other operating systems as well. I use SO and SE a lot on my phone, if you click the "enable responsiveness" at the bottom of the screen when you're on your phone, you can make use of the new responsive design. It made SE a lot less painful to use on a phone.

Comment: Ironically the footer says to download the ios app.

Comment: And the iPhone version of the web site sucks too.

Comment: I've only ever found the iOS app useful for telling me if I have comment/post notifications. It means I don't have to keep SO open when I ask a question/post an answer/leave a comment, as I almost always have my phone to hand to get these notifications. I almost never actually open the app though.