# Getting: “key is not valid for passed access_token, token not found.” when using Teams API

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, api

I'm suddenly getting this error when making API calls to my StackOverflow Team API:

```
{
    "error_id": 403,
    "error_message": "`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.",
    "error_name": "access_denied"
}
```

This is the GET request I'm trying to make:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?site=stackoverflow&team=stackoverflow.com/c/<team-name>&filter=total&key=<team-key>
```

With the following header for authentication:

```
X-API-Access-Token: <api-token>
```

I've obtained my tokens with a `no-expiry` scope, and they were working last week, but requests to the API are now returning the error above.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow app not loading content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/stack-overflow-app-not-loading-content)

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324691/stack-exchange-ios-app-not-working

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find how those questions are relevant to using the SO API. I stated in my question that I have requested new tokens to send calls to the API, yet they don't work

Comment: @CarlosMartinez oh it wasn't clear from your question. you said it was no-expiry which to me was that you had it stored.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was using a token with no expiration to access the Teams JSON API which suddenly stopped working. I've created new access tokens and yet they all return the same error message. I rechecked that the "key" and "client_id" parameters have the correct values for my application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Teams API access still works fine for me.**  Something not shown in the question is the problem.

1. Don't use `total` for the `filter`.  That filter [**omits crucial wrapper and error properties**](https://stackapps.com/a/7832/7653) and may be masking the original problem.
2. You don't mention `Client Secret` so verify that you are using [*implicit* OAuth](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).
3. Go ahead and reset the `Client Secret`, on your app's [configuration page](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/), regardless.
4. Then get a fresh access `access_token` and try again.

---

You don't show how you got your access token.  Edit the question to have a *complete* MCVE.

Comment: I disabled/enabled the option: `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` and then requested another token and the problem is solved. Weird.